# Querying many tables from a non-normalised DB with no keys

Tags: sql, database, teradata

So I have a difficult (for me) problem with a troublesome database, and am hoping you folks may be able to help me.  First, let me set the scene.  It seems a database was copied from some previous incarnation into its current database engine.  What was copied across appears to be table and column names, field types and lengths, and content.  In the entire database, there are no primary or foreign keys.  Also, the old database was not normalised, and the current database is not normalised.  To make it just a tad more fun, I do not have the option of rebuilding it all or changing anything.  The only thing I can do is run select queries.

That being the situation, I have the following relevant tables and columns:

```
Table:
    Facilities
Columns:
    Asset_ID (bigint)
    Asset_Category (bigint)

Table:
    Gardens
Columns:
    Asset_ID (bigint)
    Asset_Category (bigint)

Table:
    Equipment
Columns:
    Asset_ID (bigint)
    Asset_Category (bigint)

Table:
    Structures
Columns:
    Asset_ID (bigint)
    Asset_Category (bigint)
```

Each of those has the same types of information.  For example, Facilities may contain a lawnmower, and Gardens might also contain a lawnmower.  As I said, it is not normalised.  Data was added to different tables in that way without any consideration for usefulness or normalisation.  Every ID field is a bingint, and that's about as useful as that field gets.

Furthermore, I have the following tables:

```
Table:
    Depots
Columns:
    ID (bigint)
    Name (varchar)

Table:
    Area
Columns:
    ID (bigint)
    Site_ID (bigint)
    Name (varchar)

Table:
    Asset_Category
Columns:
    Type_ID (bigint)
    Category_ID (bigint)
    Category_Name (varchar)

Table:
    Depot_Assets
Columns:
    Depot_ID (bigint)
    Asset_ID (bigint)

Table:
    Facility_Assets
Columns:
    Asset_ID (bigint)
    Category (bigint)
```

Now I am guessing that the Asset_IDs and Category_IDs somehow magically match up across tables, that there is some degree of consistency, but given that there are no keys and no normalisation, it's impossible to determine at this point.

I have been asked to produce a report showing the number of assets of each category in each location.  I have attempted to combine results from those first four tables as follows:

```
inner join
    (select "Asset_ID", "Category" from "Facilities" union all 
    select "Asset_ID", "Category" from "Gardens" union all 
    select "Asset_ID", "Category" from "Equipment" union all 
    select "Asset_ID", "Category" from "Structures") as temp
    on (temp."Category" = "Asset_Category"."Category_ID")
```

But beyond that I am absolutely lost regarding how to get a list of assets in each category assigned to each location (by Area.Name).

Any assistance and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no relation to Area based on column names. Who asked you to produce this report? Ask him about relations, he should know the data :-) Not implementing PKs & FKs physically in a Warehouse is quite normal, but, of course, they still exist and should be documented somewhere. You should start analyzing the existing data to check for unique columns (count distinct) and then for possible FKs using NOT EXISTS

Comment: I don't see any way for us to divine how this data (including your SQL statement) is to be joined to the `Area` table. If you can explain how that relationship works, then we can help with the SQL, but right now you are in the best position to figure that out since you can see the data and take some steps to see how it joins up (up to and including asking others in your company that have worked with this). My only suggestion is to include the table name in your UNION's like `SELECT asset_id, category, 'Structures' as tablename FROM Structures...` so you know which record came from which table.